# How to use Cocos2dJS to connect to a Socket.IO server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, cocos2d-js

How can I connect to a `nodejs socket.io` server from a `cocos2djs` game? I've google all the way to no avail. I tried this but it does not work:

```
socket = io.connect('http://192.168.254.102:7714');
if ( socket === undefined ) {
    cc.log("Could not connect to socket.io");
} else {
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('join', {username: 'Android Application'})
    });
}
```

I read in the docs that there's a module called `SocketIO` for doing that, but there's not enough info on how to use it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be as simple as using Socket.io on any other JS project.. What error are you getting? As for the cocos2d-js `io` module, you need to add `"socketio"` to your `modules` list in `project.json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, By default cocos2d is compatible with socket.IO version 0.9 and not 1.0+

i am assuming you are using socket Version 1 on the server sided and hence you are unable to connect..

Solution:
this will be fixed in the upcoming cocos2d version or you can manually at
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/11583

this will allow you to connect to both the versions of Socket.IO

Comment: I read on github that they did not "expose" socketio to js. I remember reading an issue about that on the oficial repository. Btw, I decided to use the c++ bindings instead. Thanks.

Comment: @Cyberpunk that might have probably been a old post... i have tested the sample test of the socketIO in jsb and it works.. Anyways good luck with the c++ :D